# Can't get value of HTMLElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic5, tsx

I'm currently using Ionic React with .tsx files. When I do a simple `document.getElementById("input-id").value`, got the error `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'`. Looking for a way to solve this, fount the typescript parser `<HTMLInputElement>`, but doesn't work because HTMLElement doesn't have many HTMLInputElement props.

How can I get the value of an input in this context?

My code is here. It can't even compile because of Typescript erros:

```
handleChange() {
  const input = document.getElementById("id").value;
}

render() {
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <TextField
          id="id"
          label="Input"
          variant="outlined"
          required
        />
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use casting with the `as` keyword and declare a variable that you know to be of `HTMLInputElement` type. Then access its `value` property.

```
const inputElement: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById("input-id") as HTMLInputElement;
console.log(inputElement.value)
```

Comment: I tried this code on the TypeScript playground and there were no type errors. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmADgVygUQDYFMC2WxQBcMAEgCoCyAMgJJKqa76wC8MAJiMMngQHQBzLOmy8oAIQCeNdgAoARAhRQAtHHbyAlDACGEUpVr0RTAgG4AUKEghsfDCAGylDUcz4A3HRmRZNQA

Comment: it works~ aaaaahh im so freaking happy now~ thanks, Sir